# Python import error on Windows: no __path__

Tags: python, windows

OK, trying to track down this issue of running a Python package.

Running on Windows.

Only one version of Python is installed on the computer: 3.4.3

Package has been installed (package name: Willie) (details of installation are more convoluted than usual; can provide steps if necessary)

Package installed at: `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\willie`

Startup script is: `C:\Python34\Scripts\willie.py`

Error is one of the first lines of the script:

```
from willie.tools import stderr
```

If I run willie.py from the command line, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2218, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\willie.py", line 15, in <module>
    from willie.tools import stderr
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\willie.py", line 15, in <module>
    from willie.tools import stderr
ImportError: No module named 'willie.tools'; 'willie' is not a package
```

The `__path__` attribute is *supposed* to be set automatically when the `import` function is used, but it doesn't exist, which leads to the program being unable to execute.

`C:\Python34\Scripts;` is in my `Path` environment variable.

`PYTHONPATH` has been set for everything from `C:\Python34;` to `C:\Python34;C:\Python34\Lib;C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages;C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages;C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\willie;C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\willie\tools;`.

In all cases with these directories, if I try to execute the above import command from the interactive Python prompt, it runs correctly. I can use the `stderr` function, and examine its `__file__` and `__path__` fields.

If I add `C:\Python34\Scripts;` to `PYTHONPATH`, however, I get the same error as using it from the command line: `__path__` doesn't exist, 'willie' is not a package.

I do know that willie.py is being called recursively, somehow, because I can add a print() at the top of the file that runs twice.

Looking for help in figuring out how to make this run.  Is almost certainly a configuration issue on my end, but I have no idea what to do to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you absolutely do not want `c:\Python34\Scripts` in your `PYTHONPATH`. Files under `\Scripts` are NOT meant to be importable.

Second, `willie` does some screwing around to make sure `willie.py` gets installed to `c:\Python34\Scripts\willie` (note there is no `.py` suffix). This is decidedly nonstandard. The only reason this even works is because on Unix machines, the first line of that file is a special "shebang" that tells the Unix program launcher to execute the file using Python. There is no equivalent feature on Windows - naming the file `willie` with no `.py` means you simply can't execute it.

So it looks like the module `willie` is simply not prepared to be installed on Windows systems. ([#811](https://github.com/embolalia/willie/issues/811) and [#822](https://github.com/embolalia/willie/issues/822) both refer to weirdness on Windows caused by the nonstandard package setup.)

A standard package setup would have `willie.py` inside the `willie` package as `willie/main.py` and, in the package's `setup.py`, register `willie.main` as an "Entry Point" named `willie`. This incantation would create `c:\Python34\Scripts\willie.exe` on Windows systems when the package is installed using `pip`.

I believe the reason for the recursive import is because the second entry in `sys.path` is the name of the script that is run from the command line. So, it's always finding `C:\Python34\Scripts\willie.py` when it looks for the module `willie` which is not the one it needs.

As a workaround, you could try renaming `C:\Python34\Scripts\willie.py` to `C:\Python34\Scripts\run-willie.py`